# Checking for Private Class Name Grounds for Rejection from Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, class, private, mac-app-store, nsbuttoncell

I've noticed that the "stock" Aqua radio button and checkbox images are drawn using the normal `NSButtonCell` method, `-drawImage:withFrame:inView:`.

When drawing in my `NSButtonCell` subclass, I'd like to discern between a stock image being passed and an image supplied by a developer. If the image is a custom one, I want it to be used, but if it's a default interface image, I want to handle the drawing myself. Does that make sense?

Anyway, I've written a method which checks if the image is a default interface image, and it looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)isAquaInterfaceImage:(NSImage *)image
{
    return [image.representations[0] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSCoreUIImageRep")];
}
```

Since the Apple-supplied image uses a private class, I use the `NSClassFromString()` function to have it output for me at runtime so I don't get a bunch of compiler warnings. This technique works great, and with it, I can be sure whether or not the image passed to the drawing method should be drawn. The problem is, I don't want developers' apps not getting accepted to the Mac App Store just because I reference a private class.

I'm new to all of this, so I'm not exactly sure how "strict" Apple's rules are. If anyone knows where Apple draws the line in respect to using the names of private classes or frameworks, I'd love to know. Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you concerned about breaking developers' apps when, inevitably, the frameworks change and use image reps which aren't of that class? In other words, this is an approach that's doomed to fail, whether or not it gets accepted into the App Store.

Comment: @KenThomases Oh, I know. I contemplated not posting the question, but then I thought, "Apple's been using these Aqua widgets for years. Maybe I could get some mileage out of this technique before they completely ditch the current process." It's a losing battle, but it's really the only solution I can come up with. Being a designer by trade, I like to make a lot of options available to developers, so they can customize stuff as much or as little as they'd like. However, I'm trying to add very few of my own properties, though, so the API is almost identical to ones they've used a million times.